# XSLT: Copy across all the children of node based on namespace uri

Tags: xml, xslt, dynamic, matching

I am totally new to XSLT and i need to use it for some transformation. What i would like  to understand is how to copy aross the children of a particular element on an xml document.

This element is dynamic but i know the uri of its namespace. Is there a way of matching this element based on the uri, which i have, and then copying all its children across?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`xsl:copy-of`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copy-of) element can be used to copy a node-set over to the result tree.

For example, to copy child nodes in the `foo` namespace to the result, you could use something like this:

```
<xsl:copy-of xmlns:ns="foo" select="ns:*"/>
```

See also the [`xsl:copy`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) element for copying the current node.

---

*Edited to add:* If you know the namespace only at runtime, see the [`namespace-uri`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-namespace-uri) XPath function.

For example, if you have variable `$uri` containing the namespace URI, the equivalent of the above would be:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="*[namespace-uri() = $uri]"/>
```

Comment: Hi Jukka, thanks. How does that work though? In my case, foo will be a variable; so something like xmlns:ns=$uri. Perhaps there is a neater solution.

Comment: @isaiah, there is the `namespace-uri()` function which extracts the namespace URI of a node. I edited the answer to add an example.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. I was wondering, from your point of view, how can i learn xslt? I can see it's quite powerful.

Comment: @isaiah, see the answers to this (closed) question for some recommendations on books, tutorials and other resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online